# Making predictions with logistic regression (Python Sci Kit Learn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am relatively new to [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) using [SciKit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) in Python. After reading some topics and viewing some demo's, I decided to dive in myself.

So, basically, I am trying to predict the conversion rate of customers, based on some features. The outcome is either *Active* (1) or *Not active* (0). I tried *KNN* and *logistic regression*. With *KNN* I get an average accuracy of `0.893` and with logistic regression `0.994`. The latter seems so high, is that even realistic / possible?

Anyway: Suppose that my model is indeed very accurate, I would now like to import a new dataset with the same feauture columns and predict their conversions (they end this month). In the case above I used `cross_val_score` to get the accuracy scores.

Do I now need to import the new set, somehow fit that new set to this model. (not training it again, now I just want to use it)

Can someone please inform me how I can proceed? If additional info is needed, please comment on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Accuracy/misclassification rate isn't the only metric you should look at. You should also look at classwise accuracy. For ex: if you have 100 rows with 99 ones and 1 zero and your model predicts 100 for all of the rows, you still have 99% accuracy, but it might be that your model isn't good at predicting zeros. You can troubleshoot this by over/under sampling.

Comment: Once you have trained the model, you can use the predict function and pass the new data to it. Ex: if `clf` is the model object then you can use `clf.predict(test_data)`. This will return the predictions. If you use `.fit` and pass the new new dataset, the model will be updated accordingly. If you just need the predictions and dont want to alter the model you should directly use the `.predict` method. SO answering to your question, in this case you just need to predict, no fitting is required.

Comment: Thanks, in my dataset Active (1) occurs in 68%, Not Active (0) 32%. So that seems to be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the second comment. I think I in my case I could use logreg.predict(mynewdata). This was original code: 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg_scores = cross_val_score(logreg, X, y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print(logreg_scores)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the statistic question: of course, it can happen, either your data is having little noise or the scenario  Clock Slave mentioned in the comments.

For the import of the classifier, you could `pickle`   it  ( save it as a binary with the `pickle` module, and then just load it whenever you need it and use the `clf.predict()` method on the new data

```
import pickle 

#Do the classification and name the fitted object clf
with open('clf.pickle', 'wb') as file :
    pickle.dump(clf,file,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

And then later you can load it

```
import pickle 

with open('clf.pickle', 'rb') as file :
    clf =pickle.load(file)

# Now predict on the new dataframe df as 
pred = clf.predict(df.values)
```

Comment: I guess on the loading phase, it should be "rb" instead of "wb". Also, why do you need "HIGHEST_PROTOCOL"?

Comment: 1. Yeah, of course , thanks for pointing it out. Obviously, we need to read the file and not overwrite it.  2. It is more of a convention I adopted. Since as far as I know the protocol 2 aka HIGHEST_PROTOCOL is the most efficient. But you could use `2` or `-1`  instead without changing anything. Without defining the protocol it is by default 0 which would also work, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions.

Answer (score 2):

Beside 'Pickle', 'joblib' can be used as well.

```
## 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

assume there X,Y, already defined

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
```

save the model to disk

```
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
joblib.dump(model, filename)
```

load the model from disk

```
loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, Y_test)
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Nati!

Comment: Is there any advantage about using it? Indeed joblib is from scikit learn so you already have it in this context, but I would tend to use mostly the standard library options if there are no edges about joblib.